# can't populate db using rake db:populate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, populate, faker

I am trying to populate my db using rake db:populate. I am on chapter 10.3.2 on michael hartl's book.

Even though I don't get any error messages the DB doesn't seem to be populating.

This is the `sample_data.rake` file I created:

```
  namespace :db do   desc "Fill database with sample data"   task populate: :environment do
        User.create!(:name => "Example User",
                     :email => "example@railstutorial.org",
                     :password => "foobar",
                     :password_confirmation => "foobar")
        99.times do |n|
          name  = Faker::Name.name
          email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
          password  = "password"
          User.create!(:name => name,
                       :email => email,
                       :password => password,
                       :password_confirmation => password)
        end   
     end 
  end
```

Comment: ok the problem fixed itself...

Comment: I'm having the same problem, could you explain how you fixed it ?

Comment: Silly answer : restart your rails server (worked for me, don't ask me why) !

Comment: +1 This helped me solve the same problem I was having in Chapter 9 of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michale Hartl. A simple server restart did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Stopping your server before resetting and repopulating your db should work.